# How to get the ISO Day of Week using Calendar API

Tags: java, iso8601, dayofweek

I want to get the ISO Day of the Week using the `Calendar` API, but it returns the wrong day number.

Sunday is the last day of the week and should be number **7** from the ISO standard, with Monday being the first day as number 1.

But running the following code for a Sunday (2017-07-30) is returning me number **1**. Why is `Calendar` API returning me a different value?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JULY);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
```

The result is: 1

I tried using Joda Time and it worked fine, but I need to do it using Calendar and Java 6, so using another library is not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The int constants start with Sunday and end with Saturday.

Documented in [`java.util.Calendar` JavaDoc for Java 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK).

So my proposal is to calculate it on your own.

Comment: Sure, you´re right. No enum, constants. I´ve changed the answer according this.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Legacy way to determine day-of-week number defined ISO 8601 (Monday-Sunday, 1-7):

```
int dayOfWeekISO = cal.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK ) - 1 ;
if( dayOfWeekISO == 0 ) {  // For Sunday ( 1 - 1 = 0), add 7. 
    dayOfWeekISO = ( dayOfWeekISO + 1 ) ; 
}
```

Modern way:

```
LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JULY , 30 )  // Date-only value.
         .getDayOfWeek()                // `DayOfWeek.SUNDAY` enum object.
         .getValue()                    // 7 for Sunday. (1 = Monday, per ISO 8601 standard.)
```

> 7

## Details

The [accepted answer by Maia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45510239/642706) is correct: [Those `int` constants on `Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) define the week as 1-7 for [Sunday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunday)-Saturday, per the custom in the United States.

> DAY_OF_WEEK
>
> public static final int DAY_OF_WEEK
>
> Field number for get and set indicating the day of the week. This field takes values SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, and SATURDAY.

If you absolutely cannot add a library, then you must adjust from the `Calendar` definition of a week being Sunday-Saturday 1-7. To put Money in the first place, subtract 1, then check for 0 to which you add 7.

```
int dayOfWeekISO = cal.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK ) - 1 ;
if( dayOfWeekISO == 0 ) {  // For Sunday ( 1 - 1 = 0), add 7. 
    dayOfWeekISO = ( dayOfWeekISO + 1 ) ; 
}
```

By the way to go the other way, from [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) style to US-style (Sunday first), calculate [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) 7 then plus 1.

```
( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.getValue() % 7 ) + 1
```

Like this:

```
System.out.println( ( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.getValue() % 7 ) + 1 ) ;
System.out.println( ( DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getValue() % 7 ) + 1 ) ;
System.out.println( ( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY.getValue() % 7 ) + 1 ) ;
System.out.println( ( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY.getValue() % 7 ) + 1 ) ;
System.out.println( ( DayOfWeek.THURSDAY.getValue() % 7 ) + 1 ) ;
System.out.println( ( DayOfWeek.FRIDAY.getValue() % 7 ) + 1 ) ;
System.out.println( ( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY.getValue() % 7 ) + 1 ) ;
```

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 6
>
> 7

But do consider adding [a library of modern date-time classes](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Well worth the bother of adding a jar to your project. Those old date-time classes really are wretched.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The `Calendar` class is part of the troublesome old legacy date-time classes, now supplanted by java.time classes.

## java.time

The [`java.time.DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum is standard, representing a week defined by [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) where a week runs from Monday to Sunday, numbered 1-7.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JULY , 30 ) ;
DayOfWeek dow = ld.getDayOfWeek() ;
int dowNumber = dow.getValue() ;
String output = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;
```

See [this code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/DmDOg8).

> ld.toString(): 2017-07-30
>
> dow.toString(): SUNDAY
>
> dowNumber: 7
>
> output: Sunday

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check the Javadoc of Calendar for java 6 before posting a question [values of Constants in Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.MONDAY)

The value of Calendar.SUNDAY is 1 for US Locale.

Comment: The value of Calendar.SUNDAY is always the same, it does not change by locale.

Comment: Calendar.sunday is not changed by locale but day of week as 1 will change based on locale. My apologies for vague answer but my intention is different